# SharePoint prompting for credentials

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

SharePoint 2019 is keep asking for login prompt when opening any MS Office documents. It opens the document and then prompts for login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

How do you open the MS office documents? In office online or client application? If you open the documents in office client application, You can pre-login your MS office client application via File -> Account.
[image]

Comment: We use the Office on-premise to open documents.